# Better way to get a matrix of linear regression coefficients

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix

I have an xts object X

```
dput(x)
structure(c(111.09, 110.95, 110.71, 110.79, 110.72, 110.83, 110.75, 
110.74, 110.85, 110.95, 110.98, 120.99, 121.27, 120.61, 120.55, 
120.76, 120.86, 120.82, 120.88, 121.1, 120.86, 120.76, 111.29, 
111.08, 110.95, 110.88, 111.05, 111.17, 111.17, 111.17, 111.2, 
111.19, 111.28), .Dim = c(11L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("val1", 
"val2", "val3")), index = structure(c(1356987540, 1357160340, 
1357246740, 1357333140, 1357592340, 1357678740, 1357765140, 1357851540, 
1357937940, 1358197140, 1358283540), tzone = "GMT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "GMT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT", class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Its data looks like this

```
                      val1   val2   val3
2012-12-31 20:59:00 111.09 120.99 111.29
2013-01-02 20:59:00 110.95 121.27 111.08
2013-01-03 20:59:00 110.71 120.61 110.95
2013-01-04 20:59:00 110.79 120.55 110.88
2013-01-07 20:59:00 110.72 120.76 111.05
2013-01-08 20:59:00 110.83 120.86 111.17
2013-01-09 20:59:00 110.75 120.82 111.17
2013-01-10 20:59:00 110.74 120.88 111.17
2013-01-11 20:59:00 110.85 121.10 111.20
2013-01-14 20:59:00 110.95 120.86 111.19
2013-01-15 20:59:00 110.98 120.76 111.28
```

And I can get a correlation between each of the vals (val1, val2, val3) by using `cor(x, method="pearson")` and I would like a similar matrix, but instead of the correlations between the three vals, I would like the linear regression coefficient. I created a function that does exactly what I want, but R is new to me and I feel like I did it in a very C/C++ way. I hoping that maybe someone can help me create a more R-like solution (maybe using one of the apply methods, or even a link to something that would help me understand how to do operations like this).

The function that I created looks like this

```
getLmFromValues <- function( vals ) {

    #create an empty data.frame
    df <- data.frame( matrix(0, nrow = ncol(vals), ncol = ncol(vals) ) )

    colnames(df) <- colnames(vals)
    rownames(df) <- colnames(vals)

    for( outer in 1:ncol(vals) ) {

        for ( inner in 1:ncol(vals) ) {

            if ( inner == outer ) {
                df[outer,inner] <- NA #could also be 1
            }
            else {
                            #get linear model of vectors and store the slope coeficient
                df[outer, inner] <- coef( lm( vals[,outer] ~ vals[,inner] ) )[2]
            }
        }
    }

    return( df )
}
```

The output from my function looks like this

```
          val1      val2      val3
val1        NA 0.3015123 0.6071429
val2 0.8122685        NA 0.7978208
val3 0.6384838 0.3114367        NA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slope in a regression model with a single linear predictor is just $\hat\beta = \rho \times \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$.  So you can just multiply the correlation matrix by diagonal matricies based on the standard deviations:

```
mysd <- sqrt( diag( var(mydata) ) )

diag( mysd ) %*% cor(mydata) %*% diag( 1/mysd )

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.3015123 0.6071429
[2,] 0.8122685 1.0000000 0.7978208
[3,] 0.6384838 0.3114367 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? First create all possible combinations with `expand.grid`. Then, use `apply` that takes a `matrix` as its first argument, followed by an index = `1` here (for row-wise) and then it allows for a function to be defined. Note that index can also be 2 which means the values will be sent column wise, which we don't want here. Index = 1 means the values from idx will be passed as (1,1), (2,1) etc.. one at a time. And we use that to create a function that has a parameter ix that will be (1,1), (2,1) ... each time and using a simple if-else statement we construct all outputs. Then shape it to a matrix form you require. I hpe this helps.

```
idx <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)
out <- apply(idx, 1, function(ix) {
    if (all(ix==ix[1])) {
        return(NA)
    } else {
        summary(lm(x[1:11, ix[1]] ~ x[1:11, ix[2]]))$coefficients[2,1]
    }
})

> out.m <- matrix(out, ncol=3)
> out.m

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,]        NA 0.3015123 0.6071429
# [2,] 0.8122685        NA 0.7978208
# [3,] 0.6384838 0.3114367        NA
```

Comment: I love the explanation! I'm still trying to learn how to do things in an R way and this helps. Thanks!